# Using GhostScript to append a source pdf page to another pdf

Tags: pdf, append, ghostscript

I have found a way to merge two pdfs together using Ghostscript;

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=TARGET.dpf SOURCE1.pdf SOURCE2.pdf
```

I have also found a way to only use a certain page range from a source pdf;

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sOutputFile=TARGET.pdf SOURCE.pdf
```

but what I need to do is merge page 1 from document A with the whole of document B.
I know I could extract page 1 from document A to a new document (doc C) and then merge the new doc (C) with document B...

but I feel there ought to be a way to simply append to the target rather than overwritting.

Can anyone tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

Probably use a different tool, have you looked at pdftk ? Ghostscript isn't intended for 'manipulation' of PDF files, its meant to create them from different input sources. When you use Ghostscript as you describe it doesn't append the files, it creates a new file whose visual appearance is the same as the two original files. The contents may differ totally from the original.

I believe you could use MuPDF for this as well.